# Evaluating referrer from Sharepoint portal

Tags: php, iis-7, sharepoint-2010

I have an internal company site that looks something like `tools.mycompany.com`. Right now, it's only accessible from inside my local network. The way users access this page is by going to my company's sharepoint intranet that is something like: `intranet.mycompany.com`. The link to the `tools` page is there, and users can click. The intranet site can be accessed from the an 'outside' network, but AD credentials must be supplied.

The new goal is to allow 'outside' users to access the `tools.mycompany.com` page, but only through the `intranet.mycompany.com`, so they have been authenticated by AD.

My first thought would be to evaluate the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, and do something like:

```
($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'intranet.mycompany.com') ? die('Didn't come from Intranet') : '';
```

But relying on the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` seems unreliable.

Is there other options to protect my `tools.mycompany.com` page from unauthorized access? And not require authenticated users to re-enter their credentials?

Comment: have sharepoint generate a token in the "go to intranet" link. the token would be an encrypted "yes, this is an authorized click" type message, which the PHP side can decrypt. if the decryption doesn't go right, it's not an authorized click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, the level of security you can implement is up to you.

in sharepoint at the bottom of the page

```
<img src="http://tools.mycompany.com/sso/?x=encryptedstring" width="1" height="1" />
```

on tools.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    // here is where you could add some security if decrypted $_GET[x] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = 1;

?>
```

this is defiantly not the best way to do this but its a quick and easy way